# Running a macro in closed excel workbooks and merging the result into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro in several identical workbooks and then merge the first sheet of those workbooks into a new workbook. The merging part is working thanks to the Internet, but I don't seem to get the "running the macro" part down. Here's my code so far :

```
Sub MergeSelectedWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim NFile As Long
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range


Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
FolderPath = "..."
ChDrive FolderPath
ChDir FolderPath

SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

NRow = 1
For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
    ' Set FileName to be the current workbook file name to open.
    FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)

    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    Run "Détaildesmlh_Bouton1_Cliquer"  #this is what doesn't work

    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G19")
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=True
Next NFile
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I have tried different ways of getting the macro running, the code I have added above returns an error because the macro either doesn't exist or isn't active. Do you have any workarounds ? I've tried looking through solutions I found online but they either don't work with the rest of the code or seem very complicated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Run "Détaildesmlh_Bouton1_Cliquer"  #this is what doesn't work
```

above doesn't work because syntax is not correct :)

Try this.

```
Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Application.Run FileName &"!Détaildesmlh_Bouton1_Cliquer"
```

*N.B. -  you may need to strip the UNC path from the FileName if it's there and just pass workbook name (i.e. - MyBook.xlsm)*

Comment: It does open the file correctly but still says that the macro is not available in the workbook or that all macros have been deactivated. Is that where I would need to strip the UNC path ?

Comment: 1) Are you Excel options set to enable macros automatically? If not, change them 2) Is the Macro name **exactly** as it is in the workbook. If not, adjust that. 3) Is the macro in the opening workbook in a private sub? If so, make it public. 4) If the UNC path is there, you will see `\\server\folder\file\mybook.xlsm` when you print `FileName` to immediate window. If it is there, you can use string manipulation to only get file name ... actually (after writing all that) simply use `WorkBk.Name` instead of FileName.